# Where is the dhclient.conf under Fedora 14?

Tags: fedora, dhcp

I wanted to put this in the dhclient.conf file:

supersede domain-name "foo.org foo2.org";

but there is no dhclient.conf file...where is it? (Fedora14/GNOME)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vim /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you would use `/etc/dhclient.conf` which isn't created by default, so you would create it yourself of course.

From reading the `dhclient` man page, you could also run `dhclient` with the `-cf` flag to specify a config file.
For example:

```
dhclient -cf ~/dhclient.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

For NetworkManager managed ehternet ports, you might look for the file `/var/run/nm-dhclient-ethX.conf`.